# MobileFirst 7.0 - Invoking sample Java SQL Adapter with REST API fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am following the [Java SQL Adapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-sql-adapter/comment-page-1/) tutorial for MobileFirst Platform 7.
Im trying to create a new user by using REST call type `@POST`, but the chrome console is

> POST http://192.168.56.1:10080/JavaAdapters/adapters/UserAdapter/?userId=test&lastName=test&firstName=test&password=test 409 (Conflict)

and the response is

> Column 'userId' cannot be null

I think the params of this procedure are set with null value

This is my code

```
var userId = "test";var lastName = "test";var firstName = "test";var password = "test";

function createUser(userId,lastName,firstName,password){
  busyIndicator.show();
  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/UserAdapter/", WLResourceRequest.POST);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("userId", userId);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("lastName", lastName);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("firstName", firstName);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("password", password);
  resourceRequest.send().then(
        createUserSuccess,
        createUserFailure
);}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are sending a `POST` request to the adapter you should not be using `setQueryParameter` because that is designed for `GET` requests, you should use `sendFormParameters` instead of `send`. Your updated code should look like this:

```
function createUser(userId, lastName, firstName, password){
  busyIndicator.show();
  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/UserAdapter/", WLResourceRequest.POST);
  var user = {
    "userId": userId,
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "password": password
  };

  resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(user).then(createUserSuccess).fail(createUserFailure);
}
```